# Why does moving AND rotating a NSView change its rotation center to the frame's origin?

Tags: objective-c, rotation, nsview, transformation

I rotate a NSView around its center and verified the result:

```
[_cocoaView setFrameCenterRotation:-_rotationX];
```

[image]
[image]

I position the NSView by changing the frame origin so that the view is aligned with (in this case) a Box2D body's center. Again the result is as expected:

```
CGRect frame = _cocoaView.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(_position.x - frame.size.width * 0.5f, 
                           _position.y - frame.size.height * 0.5f);
_cocoaView.frame = frame;
```

[image]

However, once I combine both translation and rotation, the center of rotation is no longer the view's center but some other point. I believe the frame size & origin change as a result of the rotation, thereby shifting the center point of the frame. The result is that the view and Box2D body no longer align unless rotation angle is 0.

[image]

**Why is that? And how can I translate the view to a specific location AND rotate the view around its center?**

PS: [my previous attempt at applying the already working affine transformation of the iOS version to the layer-backed NSView failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003803/how-to-apply-a-view-transformation-that-works-for-a-uiview-to-a-nsview). So I tried it without using transforms, but alas, again I'm stuck. If you know how to make it work with layers and transforms that would help me out, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was two-fold. To fix the incorrect rotation, I first need to set rotation to 0, move the origin, then apply the actual rotation.

However this caused a lot of flicker to occur while the view was rotated and moved. Randomly, and quite frequently, the view would jump to a different position, rotate incorrectly or be cut off - or all of that. The solution to that issue was to enclose the translate & rotate code within lockFocus and unlockFocus calls.

Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
    [_cocoaView lockFocusIfCanDraw];
    [_cocoaView setFrameCenterRotation:0];

    CGSize frameSize = _cocoaView.frame.size;
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(_position.x - frameSize.width * 0.5f, _position.y - frameSize.height * 0.5f);
    [_cocoaView setFrameOrigin:origin];

    [_cocoaView setFrameCenterRotation:-_rotationX];
    [_cocoaView unlockFocus];
```

Only downside: the view still seems to lag a little behind the Box2D body occasionally. Hardly noticable, so it's not perfect but good enough for now.